# How to use onSubmit() in jsp?

Tags: jsp, onsubmit, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdown list in JSP page. When a user selects a option I need to update the value into database using `onSubmit()`. I need some help in executing update query using `onSubmit`.

mycode:

```
<% 
String query = "SELECT * FROM MONEY_ISSUE_REQUEST WHERE QUEUE_ID='q1'";
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query); %>

<table border="1"> 
     <tr>               
         <th style=font-weight:bold>  REQ_ID &nbsp;  &nbsp; </th> 
         (...)       
         <th style=font-weight:bold>  APPROVAL &nbsp; &nbsp; </TH>
     </tr>

     <% while(rs.next()) { %>
     <tr>
         <td> <%out.println(rs.getInt(1));%> </td>
         (...)
         <td> <%out.println(rs.getString(13));%> </td>
         <td>
             <select name="id" onchange="update('this.options[this.selectedIndex].value')" >
                 <option value="approve">approve</option>
                 <option value="reject">reject</option>
             </select>                           
         </td>
      <% }%></tr>
</table>
```

My update query:

```
update table money_issure_request set STATUS_ID=value, QUEUE_ID='q2';
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to submit the form on `onchage` event. Assuming jQuery, here is the code example which does that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#target").change(function() {
        $("#yourForm").submit();
    });
});

<form id="yourForm" action="UpdateServlet" method="post">
  <select id="target">
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And in your update servlet you write the logic which updates database record depending on selected option.